# Bluetooth speakers controls don't work with Spotify on macOS

Tags: audio, bluetooth, spotify

I own the [UE Boom 2](http://www.ultimateears.com/en-us/ueboom2), a bluetooth speaker that has "Tap Controls" that allow pause, play and skip track. These features work fine when I'm using iTunes or soundcloud, but when I use the Spotify app, triggering the actions does nothing. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is Spotify in the foreground or background when you have this problem?

Comment: Have this same issue, pressing the play/pause button on my BT earbuds while playing Spotify opens iTunes.